# Umbraco 7.3 glass.mapper vs BoC.Glass.Mapper

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, glass-mapper

I want to add glass mapper to a new install of Umbraco, but there are two versions available: BoC and regular. I know in Sitecore the BoC version is a branch of glass mapper version 3 so project using Glass do not have to upgrade to keep current.

In Umbraco as far as I'm aware version 4 has not been released (and actually is not fully compatible with 7.3), so what is the difference between the two in relation to Umbraco?

Comment: I don't think Glass Mapper is the best tool to use for umbraco, been a while since it was updated for umbraco. @heilch

Comment: I came to that conclusion as well, I scrapped it and am using ditto. It works much much better than either version of glass